# Apache: I have lost my private.key, is it possible to re-create it from certificate.crt?

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl, certificates

I lost my `private.key` file, which is necessary for the proper operation of my SSL certificate. I have only the `certificate.crt` file.

Is it possible to generate `private.key` file from `certificate.crt` file? From what I've read, I do not think so. If I'm wrong, I don't know how to do it.

What can I do to submit the `certificate.crt` so that it works?

Apache requires all of:

- `certificate.crt`
- `intermediate.pem`
- `private.key`

files; for example:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/crt/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/crt/intermediate.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/crt/private.key
```

Answer (score 13):

No, it is not possible to generate the `private.key` file from the `certificate.crt` file. You will need to generate a new key and a new certificate, if the below does not apply to you.

You may ask your certificate provider if they're willing to re-generate your certificate, a few companies offer the possibility.

Answer (score 5):

As already said by @John, this is not possible. The SSL certificate `.crt` contains the public key; and in asymmetric cryptography it is not possible to recover the private key from the public key.

Note also that the SSL certificate must be publicly accessible in order to be used; it's presented by the HTTPS webserver to each client that connects, so it's kind of logic one can't use it to derive the private key.

So the `certificate.crt` is now useless. You need to generate a new key pair and send a CSR to the CA so that they can send you a fresh certificate.

Also note that:

- `SSLCertificateFile` specifies your SSL certificate, containing your public key and signed by the CA;
- `SSLCertificateKeyFile` specifies your private key associated with your public key;
- `SSLCertificateChainFile` specifies the certificate chain, it is not a mandatory parameter [and it has in fact been deprecated in newer versions of Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#SSLCertificateChainFile):

  > `SSLCertificateChainFile` became obsolete with version 2.4.8, when `SSLCertificateFile` was extended to also load intermediate CA certificates from the server certificate file.